# fork+exec process with threads broken on macOS? - children process stuck in _atfork_child

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, fork, exec

We have a somewhat bigger C++ application for macOS. This app at some point has multiple threads, that call `fork` and almost immediately after that `exec`. There is nothing special between `fork` and `exec`, just some `dup2` and `close` of pipes, no locks, no dynamic allocation. Other parent process threads may do some dynamic allocation when `fork` is called, but I thought that shouldn't matter.

We're sometimes seeing that after fork, the child process don't even wake up from the `fork`, it hangs for a long time and when we attach debugger to it, we see the following stack trace:

```
* thread #1, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff79e0234a libsystem_kernel.dylib`syscall_thread_switch + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff79e7926a libsystem_malloc.dylib`tiny_malloc_should_clear + 547
    frame #2: 0x00007fff79e78f96 libsystem_malloc.dylib`szone_malloc_should_clear + 66
    frame #3: 0x00007fff79e7a188 libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_zone_calloc + 99
    frame #4: 0x00007fff79e7a108 libsystem_malloc.dylib`calloc + 30
    frame #5: 0x00007fff79da4a62 libsystem_coreservices.dylib`_dirhelper_init + 460
    frame #6: 0x00007fff79eafacb libsystem_platform.dylib`_os_once_callout + 18
    frame #7: 0x00007fff79da5ebb libsystem_coreservices.dylib`_libcoreservices_fork_child + 52
    frame #8: 0x00007fff76a1bb09 libSystem.B.dylib`libSystem_atfork_child + 39
    frame #9: 0x00007fff79d26d97 libsystem_c.dylib`fork + 40
...
```

So if I understand correctly, the child process didn't even return from `fork`.

AFAIK our app doesn't do anything special, like installing custom atfork handlers and such. We don't use Objective C stuff. I thought this [new fork behavior for Objective C](http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2017/6/5/Objective-C_and_fork_in_macOS_1013.html) could be the reason, so we tried to disable that (adding `__DATA,__objc_fork_ok` section), but the problem still appears.

Does somebody here have an idea what could be the cause?

So far it seems that `fork` in multi-threaded environment is just broken on macOS. This problem doesn't happen too often, just sometimes - the more annoying it is. I'm not sure what can be wrong on our side - when the child process keeps hanging in system code, it doesn't even get to execute our code.

One idea - it's possible that `fork` gets called at the same time from multiple threads. Can that cause a problem, can only one thread at a time call `fork`?

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Fork is safe, just be careful about what is being done between fork and exec.

Comment: Sounds like it may be a variation of the problem explained here: https://www.wefearchange.org/2018/11/forkmacos.rst.html

Comment: We ended up moving to `posix_spawn` and we haven't had that problem since then. `posix_spawn` is what `NSTask` uses under the hood too. Don't know, I read there are many dangers when using `fork` on macOS, I guess it's true.